# Why "Android resource linking failed" error appears when i lower the Target SDK from 28 to 27?

Tags: android, androidx

I am using Whatsapp sticker source code to build my own sticker app. when i build this project with Target SDK version 28 or 29 it compiles flawless but when i lower the *Target SDK version to 27* then it **fails to link the resources.**I want this code to work on Android Oreo devices too.

> It is to be noted that Whatsapp migrated their code to **Androidx**
>   recently.

**Build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    //the compression of webp file during build causes problem with FileDescriptor in ContentProvider.
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "webp"
    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.sticker.app'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        def contentProviderAuthority = applicationId + ".stickercontentprovider"
        // Creates a placeholder property to use in the manifest.
        manifestPlaceholders =
                [contentProviderAuthority: contentProviderAuthority]
        // Adds a new field for the authority to the BuildConfig class.
        buildConfigField("String",
                "CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY",
                "\"${contentProviderAuthority}\"")
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/*/libnative-imagetranscoder.so'
        exclude 'lib/*/libnative-filters.so'
    }

    // Configures multiple APKs based on ABI.
    // see https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
//    splits {
//        abi {
//            enable true // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
//            universalApk true // Specifies that we do not want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
//        }
//    }
}

task checkDebug {
    doLast {
        println("checkDebug")
        if (android.defaultConfig.applicationId.startsWith("com.whatsapp")) {
            throw new GradleException("applicationId in defaultConfig cannot start with com.whatsapp, please change your applicationId in app/build.gradle")
        }
        checkApplicationIdInDebug()
    }
}

private void checkApplicationIdInDebug() {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
    def ignoreApplicationIdCheck = properties.getProperty('ignoreApplicationIdCheck')
    if (ignoreApplicationIdCheck == null) {
        if (android.defaultConfig.applicationId == "com.example.samplestickerapp") {
            throw new GradleException("Your applicationId is currently com.example.samplestickerapp, please change your applicationId to a different string in app/build.gradle in line 10")
        }
    } else {
        println("application id check ignored")
    }
}


task checkRelease {
    doLast {
        println("checkRelease")
        if (android.defaultConfig.applicationId.startsWith("com.example")) {
            throw new GradleException("applicationId in defaultConfig cannot start with com.example, please change your applicationId in app/build.gradle")
        }
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    println(task.name)
    if (task.name.contains("assembleDebug")) {
        task.dependsOn checkDebug
    }
    if (task.name.contains("assembleRelease")) {
        task.dependsOn checkRelease
    }
}
```

**Build.gradle Dependencies:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base:2.0.0'
}
```

I have searched ways to lower the Target SDK on Androidx project but haven't found any yet.

**ERROR:**

```
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\vivek\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\37ec02f661e3547c5499ecdfd9f3cd1f\\appcompat-1.1.0\\res\\values-v28\\values-v28.xml","position":{"startLine":4,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":217,"endLine":7,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":442}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\vivek\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\37ec02f661e3547c5499ecdfd9f3cd1f\\appcompat-1.1.0\\res\\values-v28\\values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\vivek\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\37ec02f661e3547c5499ecdfd9f3cd1f\\appcompat-1.1.0\\res\\values-v28\\values-v28.xml","position":{"startLine":8,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":447,"endLine":11,"endColumn":12,"endOffset":684}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\vivek\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\37ec02f661e3547c5499ecdfd9f3cd1f\\appcompat-1.1.0\\res\\values-v28\\values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\vivek\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\c527b78844be871c44103f6f45a963fb\\core-1.1.0\\res\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":141,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":8780,"endLine":172,"endColumn":24,"endOffset":10840}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\vivek\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\c527b78844be871c44103f6f45a963fb\\core-1.1.0\\res\\values\\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\vivek\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\c527b78844be871c44103f6f45a963fb\\core-1.1.0\\res\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":141,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":8780,"endLine":172,"endColumn":24,"endOffset":10840}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\vivek\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\c527b78844be871c44103f6f45a963fb\\core-1.1.0\\res\\values\\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\vivek\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\37ec02f661e3547c5499ecdfd9f3cd1f\\appcompat-1.1.0\\res\\values\\values.xml","position":{"startLine":2771,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":173278,"endLine":2794,"endColumn":24,"endOffset":174475}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\vivek\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\37ec02f661e3547c5499ecdfd9f3cd1f\\appcompat-1.1.0\\res\\values\\values.xml:2772:5-2795:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/textFontWeight not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\vivek\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\37ec02f661e3547c5499ecdfd9f3cd1f\appcompat-1.1.0\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

     C:\Users\vivek\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\37ec02f661e3547c5499ecdfd9f3cd1f\appcompat-1.1.0\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

     C:\Users\vivek\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\c527b78844be871c44103f6f45a963fb\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

     C:\Users\vivek\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\c527b78844be871c44103f6f45a963fb\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

     C:\Users\vivek\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\37ec02f661e3547c5499ecdfd9f3cd1f\appcompat-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:2772:5-2795:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/textFontWeight not found.
```

Comment: "I want this code to work on Android Oreo devices too." – The `targetSdkVersion` does not dictate which Android versions your app will, or won't, run on. As long as your `minSdkVersion` is 26 or below, it will be able to be run on Oreo. You should leave the `targetSdkVersion` at the newest version.

Comment: This is my exact problem. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

To use **androidx** libraries you have to use

```
compileSdkVersion 28
```

or higher.

You can check the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx#using_androidx):

> **If you want to use AndroidX i**n a new project, **you need to set the compile SDK to Android 9.0 (API level 28) or higher** and set both of the following Android Gradle plugin flags to true in your gradle.properties file.
>   - `android.useAndroidX`: When set to `true`, the Android plugin uses the appropriate AndroidX library instead of a Support Library. The flag is `false` by default if it is not specified.
>   - `android.enableJetifier`: When set to `true`, the Android plugin automatically migrates existing third-party libraries to use AndroidX by rewriting their binaries. The flag is `false` by default if it is not specified.

Answer (score 1):

Your app will work on any device that runs at least API level of 15. It's defined by this `minSdkVersion = 15` line. You still can use AndroidX dependencies without a problem. So try to keep `targetSdkVersion` up-to-date. In your case, you can simply keep it as is, no need to lower it. Again minimum API level you want yur app to run is defined by `minSdkVersion` not `targetSdkVersion.`

**EDIT**

To use AndroidX you need to set your compile version to at least `compileSdkVersion = 28`. In your case it's `27`. Also add these two lines into your `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.useAndroidX = true
android.enableJetifier = true // This will ensure that third-party libraries will be migrated to AndroidX
```

Comment: Sorry but I read somewhere that androidx only supports android p and later versions only. And if I use all default configuration the app installs on android pie device but it doesn't install on a Oreo device. It says app not installed

Comment: @Vivekroy, I don't know where have you read that. But that source apparently is not a reliable source or you may have misinterpreted the content. Please check the edited answer. `targetSdkVersion` won't interfere with AndroidX